# is it possible to make the functional update form of React.useState more strict in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in the following React code:

```js
const [, setOptions] = useState({
  hello: "world",
});

useEffect(() => {
  // error: Object literal may only specify known properties
  setOptions({ hello: "world", bye: "world" });
  // ok
  setOptions((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, bye: "world" }));
}, []);
```

updating state directly gives a typescript error, while the [functional update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) does not. is it possible to make the latter as strict as the former?

Comment: No, and that's not specific to useState: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oAoCUGB8UA3lAGYD25AXFAM7ABOyaAvgNwBQHAxuUvVGCJUNeMwzY86QlhIVqUAEQBGAEwBmRQBooAIwCGDGgBYArADYoLHJyA. The function you're passing *does* return an object with the required string-typed `hello` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I believe you can do the following:

```
interface Foo = { hello: string, bye, string };
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState<Foo | null>({hello: 'world', bye: 'world'})
```

That should allow for some stricter code.